# Can 2.40 tires fit a 20 inch rim?

Tags: wheels

Can 2.40 tires fit a 20 inch rim/wheel. I want move up from 2.35 tires but I'm not sure if I  have to buy bigger rims/wheels or if I can ride it with the 20 inch wheels.

Answer (score 7):

Your question can't be answered as written.

The rim diameter (20") is not directly correlated with the tyre width.

Since your frame can fit a 2.35" wide tyre, there's a very good chance a 2.4" tyre will fit.  However it is an increase of 2.1% so if you're running close now you may be out of luck.

The only time the rim dictates tyre width is the inner width of the valley of the rim.

[image: https://gzmyu4ma9b-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mavic-ETRTO-ISO-rim-width-and-tire-standards-chart.gif]

So your 2.35" tyre is 59mm moving to 2.4" which is 61mm.  Chart suggests your rim will be fine.

TL;DR your frame is the limiting factor, not the rim.